# How to construct filter for Elastic Search on Log Stash with NEST?

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, nest

I have a logstash/elasticsearch/kibana system set up and structured json type logs are getting into elastic search (not from a C# application) and visible in kibana.

I am using NEST because I would  like to slice the data from logstash.

The following code is producing "hits" results that I can inspect in the debugger.

```
ElasticClient client = new ElasticClient(settings);


var searchResults = client.Search( s  => s
                                      .From(0)
                                      .Size(100)
                                      .AllIndices()

                                      .SortDescending("@timestamp")
                                  );
```

However, if I try to expand the search to include something I believe to be present in the log (visible in Kibana), I get now results.

```
 var searchResults = client.Search( s  => s
                                      .From(0)
                                      .Size(100)
                                      .AllIndices()
                                      .Query(q => q
                                         .Term("MySpecialFieldName", "ValueThatAppears")
                                       )
                                       .SortDescending("@timestamp")
                                   );
```

I would also like to take advantage of the type safety and other mechanisms shown in the samples. I am not sure if that is expected to be related.

( I am working on figuring that out separately:  Adding a class like "client.Search(  to the search seems to prevent the results as well, I am assuming that something about the class is not aligned with the data and is therefore unable to deserialize or is otherwise filtering...)

Comment: In using the interactive query tool I see that logstash fields end up named "log.MySpecialFieldName.Raw".  I have tried this with no success so far, is this the right direction? Getting the term correct?

Answer (score 1):

Found the correct settings to make this work:

The logstash system puts this into a type (log or logs I think) when it gets indexed by elastic search. Also the term needs to be suffixed with  ".raw". So the working example ends up being:

```
 var searchResults = client.Search<MyClass>( s  => s
                                      .From(0)
                                      .Size(100)
                                      .AllIndices()
                                      .AllTypes()
                                      .Query(q => q
                                         .Term("MySpecialFieldName.raw", "ValueThatAppears")
                                       )
                                       .SortDescending("@timestamp")
                                   );
```

Comment: To strongly type this you could do `.Term(p=>p.MySpecialFieldName.Suffix("raw"), "")` You present a special use case that might benefit from built in support. If NEST came with Logstash DTO classes in Nest.Logstash namespace would you use that?

Comment: Yeah, in this case I am only using nest to process logstash data